# "insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue" Ubuntu running phyloflash

Tags: java, linux, bioinformatics

I am trying to run PhyloFlash on a a linux system (ubuntu) and I am receiving the following error:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 10737418240 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/syrenawhitner/phyloFlash-pf3.4/hs_err_pid10007.log
```

I am running Ubuntu on a WSL subsystem on windows 11, with an i7 processor, 12GB RAM, and 377GB free on my SSD. I have a feeling I need to make sure Ubuntu can access this memory, but I am not sure how to go about this, or troubleshoot this issue in general.

If anybody can assist me with this process moving forward that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Syrena

Comment: What does `free` in Ubuntu give you as free space? Especially the "available" column is of interest

Comment: WSL defaults to 50% of the available Windows memory.  You can't allocate 10GB on a 12GB machine.

Comment: total        used            free        shared     buff/cache   available
Mem:        5978616      258160     2313824         124     3406632     5427552
Swap:       2097152       20616     2076536

Comment: It pasted strange, but the "available" column gives me 5427552